# How to get a university diploma apostilled from outside the USA and how long will it take to acquire?

Tags: usa, paperwork, legal

The university I applied to wants an apostille (legalization) of my diploma for my degree. I'm not sure how to acquire this apostille as I will not be returning to the United States anytime soon.

Presently I need to remain in my current country.

How do I acquire this? Can I get it at a foreign US embassy in the country I am residing in? Or is there a mail method and if so, how? Lastly, how long do you think it will take?

Comment: Please post on Expatriates.SE instead, and please state the country you are applying in, the state where you got your degree in, and the source college

Comment: also see if there's anything useful on [academia.se] which might actually be a better site for this question

Comment: Despite the immature behavior pattern of the OP, the question is still valid and should not be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The US Departement of State [website](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/records-and-authentications/authenticate-your-document/authentication-of-american-academic-credentials.html) on educational credentials state :

> > ### Authentication of American Academic Credentials for Use Abroad
>
> U.S. embassies and consulates **cannot authenticate** diplomas or other
> documents from universities and other schools in the United States. If
> you want to present academic credentials from the United States for
> use abroad, follow the step-by-step guidance on this page for each
> type of school.

> > #### Colleges, Universities and Other Post-Secondary Institutions
>
> - Obtain from the registrar of the University an official true copy of the credentials. The registrar should then execute an affidavit
>   attesting to the validity of the document before a notary public.
>   Frequently the business offices of colleges and universities have
>   notaries public.
> - Take the document, with the notarial certificate to the state Notary Public Administrator for authentication. If the country where the
>   document will be used is a party to the Hague Apostille Convention,
>   the state Notary Public Administrator will affix an Apostille
>   certificate and no further authentication is necessary. See the Hague
>   Conference on Private International Law Apostille Page for a current
>   list of countries party to the treaty. The treaty is in force many
>   countries throughout the world.
> - If the country is not a party to the Hague Apostille Convention, the state Notary Public Administrator will affix a state authentication
>   certificate. You should then send the document to the Authentications
>   Office of the Department of State, following the instruction on that
>   office’s web page.
> - If necessary, obtain authentication of the U.S. Department of State seal at the foreign embassy in Washington, D.C. The embassy in
>   Washington, DC of the country in which the document is to be used can
>   tell you if this is required.

> > #### Primary and Secondary Schools
>
> - Obtain a transcript from the school, the principal or other authorized official should then execute an affidavit attesting to the
>   validity of the document before a notary public.
> - Take the document, with the notarial certificate to the state Notary Public Administrator for application of the state seal. If the country
>   where the document will be used is a party to the Hague Apostille
>   Convention, the state Notary Public Administrator will affix an
>   Apostille certificate and no further authentication is necessary. See
>   the Hague Conference on Private International Law Apostille Page for a
>   current list of countries party to the treaty. The treaty is in force
>   many countries throughout the world.
> - If the country is not a party to the Hague Apostille Convention, the state Notary Public Administrator will affix a state authentication
>   certificate. You should then send the document to the Authentications
>   Office of the Department of State, following the instruction on that
>   office’s web page.
> - If necessary, obtain authentication of the U.S. Department of State seal at the foreign embassy in Washington, D.C. The embassy in
>   Washington, DC of the country in which the document is to be used can
>   tell you if this is required.

It is extremely likely that you will need to know someone in the US that you can give power of attorney to for them to do the apostille with the notary public. Contacting the school that issued your degree might be helpful

Comment: Pasting an entire website most or all of which is not relevant, isn't helpful. It does not specifically address my situation. Moreover, I am not allowed to mail an official transcript to myself. So there would be no way for me to apostille it if I cannot mail to myself. Copying and pasting a full webpage is not an answer. You should answer concisely and then if desired paste the link to support your answer. Moreover, your final comment is blatantly unsupported and almost certainly categorically false.

Comment: @traveladdict This **is** the official way to get the apostille regarding the US part of it. The first paragraph mentions that you can only do that in the US, and that US foreign representations cannot do that for you. The last comment is in relation to the fact that they may require you (or a trusted person) to be there when they apostille the document. And, I don't see how you wouldn't be allowed to mail yourself the certificate once apostilled

Comment: You don't need to be physically present to obtain the apostille.  You can have someone do it for you.  Formal power of attorney is not necessary.

Comment: @expat No, it is not wrong, since it answers one part of your question: **Can I get it at a foreign US embassy in the country I am residing in?** and the answer is no as quoted in the first paragraph: *U.S. embassies and consulates **cannot authenticate** diplomas or other documents from universities and other schools in the United States.*

Comment: @expat Good for you that you **finally** figured out what most peaple know allready: that most [notaries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary) offer apostille services. That is, however, no reason to be rude.

Comment: @MarkJohnson there are services that can be found on the web that assist in obtaining apostilles. Some notaries public in the US also assist with apostilles. As a US notary public, I can state that only a tiny percentage of US notaries are ready to help with apostilles. Also, expat should check with the two universities about what credential should be supplied; normally US universities will only issue one diploma but will issue an unlimited number of other credentials, such as transcripts.

Comment: @phoog although no power of attorney is needed to obtain an apostille, it may be necessary to obtain a fresh credential from the university. Because of the privacy of academic records the university might require a power of attorney or similar permission to obtain the credential.

Comment: @expat I gave you no answer about telling you to give someone power of attorney, that was someone else. Also your meantioning of apostille was background information of you question. And please stop **vandalizing** your other posts with **nulls**, they will only be rolled back: see [How should we treat posts that are vandalized by their original authors? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106812/531408)